# Open compose email with an attachment using Javacsript/jQuery/Ajax/C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to open the compose email action along with an attachment in C# MVC application.

The behavior should be like how it happens when we click on anchor tags with mailto in href, I need to have an attachment in addition to this

```
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com?cc=someoneelse@theirsite.com, another@thatsite.com, me@mysite.com&bcc=lastperson@theirsite.com&subject=Big%20News">Email Us</a>
```

I have an action in controller that returns pdf content, is there a way to download that file and open the compose email window with this file as attachments?

I am ok with using C#/ ajax or anything else as well

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is not possible. you can do an alternative approach in which you can upload the file on the server, get the uploaded path for the file and append the path in message body of mailto.
ref:https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/mailto.html

or 
Implement the server side email routine.